# React: infinite render on useEffect only when using an internal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this following code `Parent` and `DataFilter`.

**Parent.js**

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState()

  ...

  const Filter = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Filter your data</h2>
        <DataFilter data={filteredData} updateFilter={setFilteredData} />
        <Result data={filteredData} />
      </div>
    )
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <Filter />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**DataFilter.js**

```js
const DataFilter = ({ data, updateFilter }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(defaultFilters.name)
  const [age, setAge] = useState(defaultFilters.age)
  
    ...(filter logic using data)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    updateFilter({ name, age })
  }, [name, age])
}
```

Here, I receive `Maximum update depth exceeded` aka infinite rendering, which I kind of know why.

1. `Parent` and `DataFilter` get rendered
2. `DataFilter` triggers `Parent`'s `setFilteredData` in `useEffect`
3. `Parent` gets rerendered because of `setFilteredData`
4. `Parent` being rerendered triggers child component `DataFilter`rerender
5. Repeat from No.2

But, this only started happening only after I extracted `Filter` in 'Parent' as an inner component... I know it's weird but it was working fine when `Parent` was like this

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState()

  ...

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Header</h1>
        <div>
          <h2>Filter your data</h2>
          <DataFilter data={filteredData} updateFilter={setFilteredData} />
          <Result data={filteredData} />
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Does anyone know why the infinite rendering happens only when it's as an inner component?

I tried using `useCallback` for `setFilteredData` but it didn't work.

Also what should I do to prevent the infinite render if I want to keep it as a component rather than directly writing everything in a return()?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be doing that, but can I ask why not just keep `Filter` as it's own component? It would also allow it to be reused elsewhere in your codebase in the future

Comment: @LovingGarlic That's what I'm trying to do, creating the `Filter` component, but that's causing infinite rendering here.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct from what I can gather.

To rephrase:

The child components triggers the parent component's `setFilteredData`.

When state changes in the parent component the parent will re-render it's children, which will cause the `<DataFilter>` (along with other children) to be re-rendered, which causes the useEffect to run again [since useEffect runs on every render.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#:%7E:text=Does%20useEffect%20run,runs%20the%20effects.)

This process repeats, causing the parent's state to update and again re-render. And this continues in an infinite loop.

The reason it worked with with your previous structure I believe was due to the nesting of the components, with the parents changes only updating relevant children (as opposed to the longer chain of nesting like your current setup).

If you want it not to always re-render, I'd either keep the relevant logic in the child so the child is responsible for only its own state and re-renders, instead of the parent state changes causing the child to re-render.

Alternatively, I would look at wrapping the child in [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) HOC which will limit re-renders depending on the props.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you elaborate on "keep the relevant logic in the child"? What should I do if I want delegate updating the parent's state to its child component?

Comment: Any state changes that happen should be localised to the child. If the state of the parent changes, it'll re-render its children (unless you work around it with something like React.memo).
Alternatively, flip it on its head and only pass props to child component (with out child having state itself, getting all values from parent props)

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, but in my case I want to pass filteredData to <Result filteredData={filteredData}> inside Parent.  Btw for some reason React.memo(Filter) didn't work and still triggered infinite rendering..